# Can't export TensorFlow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, object-detection

So, I followed the [instructions](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html) and ran the script to export my model after training was done. Now, I don't know why, but I keep getting this error:

> ```
> > ValueError: Tensor's shape (3, 3, 256, 12) is not compatible with
> > supplied shape (3, 3, 256, 546)
> ```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Can you try to follow the steps that mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9133#issuecomment-746064865) and let us know the update. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue trying to export a model with the Object Detection API, in my case I was using the model "ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8" from Model Zoo.

Basically, you have to:

1. Save checkpoints of your fine-tuned model.
2. Modify the "pipeline.config" file of the model you retrained in order to match the number of classes of your custom dataset; i.e, changing the value of "num_classes" properly (If the number of classes is not properly set, then the shapes of the graph won't match)
3. Use the [exporter_main_v2](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/exporter_main_v2.py) helper function to export the model for inference with the files you generated in steps 1 and 2.

I guess that you did steps 1 and 3, but not step 2.

I provide a detailed explanation of this solution in [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AbKtpAJzetnWTxhbxOVGoc0DH1IeI8PQ#scrollTo=w3gxWtZ1RJ-t), where few shot fine-tuning on a custom dataset is performed and the resulting model is exported, loaded and tested.